# Vertically centering 3 divs in another div

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in a container:

```
<div id="container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <div id="left">
    An image goes here.
  </div>

  <div id="center">
    Lorem ipsum whatever.
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the three inner divs next to each other and aligned
vertically. Using `float: left` and `float: right` for the `left` and
`right` div requires to change the order of divs and have `center` at
the end, which is not possible for me.

How can I achieve the following with CSS and this div structure:

[image]

Comment: is `position:absolute` an option?

Comment: will you specify the width? (px, em, %, whatever)

Comment: @Edditoria `container` should be at 100%, `left` is fixed at `120px` `right` should be as large as necessary and `center` should take up the rest of the `100%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css, use `display:inline-block` to align vertically,

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/BEHdu/1/

```
#left, #center, #right{
    display:inline-block; 
    *display:inline; /*IE7 fix*/
    zoom:1;
    padding:5px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#left{
    width:50px; /*Remove or Increase the width if needed*/
}

#center{
    /*SET WIDTH HERE*/
}

#left{
    /*SET WIDTH HERE*/
}
```

Comment: But it breaks the box-model for larger images. (Fixed it by myself) brain failure!

Comment: In css, try removing the `width` or increase the `width` size in `#left`.

Comment: Looks good. Unfortunately this breaks when the text in the center div is too long. How can I force it to break the content?

Comment: Set some `width` for `#center` div like `#center{width:250px}`

Comment: I updated my answer above. You can set `width` or any additional styles and you can control using CSS

Comment: @MuthuKumaran That is good, but setting a width prevents the middle div from scaling. When more space is available. I'd like it to use up as much space as possible.